# C# Preprocesors directive with (c# Version)

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Is there any way with a preprocessor to execute code according to the version of C#?
Example:

```
#if CSharpVersion = 7.3
var value = 1;
#endif
```

Comment: I have never seen a legitimate case of when preprocessor directives should be used. Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option would be to define the [`LangVersion`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version) explicitly in the Project file and have the constants defined based on it. For example,

```
<LangVersion>7.3</LangVersion>
```

and

```
<DefineConstants Condition="'$(LangVersion)' == '7.3'">DEBUG;TRACE;LANG_VERSION_7_3</DefineConstants>
<DefineConstants Condition="'$(LangVersion)' != '7.3'">DEBUG;TRACE;LANG_VERSION_NOT_7_3</DefineConstants>
```

Now you could use directives as

```
#if LANG_VERSION_7_3
            Console.WriteLine("C# 7_3");
#elif LANG_VERSION_NOT_7_3
            Console.WriteLine("Not C# 7_3");
#endif
```

Please note the `LANG_VERSION` would signify the compiler accepts syntax specified version or lower.